# threejs: optimize vertices and faces

Tags: 3d, three.js

We are using threejs to develop some 3D scenes in WebGL. We often find ourselves with geometries that have vertices in 5/6 figures (say anywhere between 50K to 200K vertices). The thing is these geometries are built using primitive threejs geometries (e.g Spheres and TubeGeometry). 
So my question is are there know techniques that can be applied to reduced the number of vertices but still maintaining reasonable quality in geometries? Here are couple of examples geometries as a example.

1. A merged geometry of 30/35 spheres e.g with THREE.SphereGeometry( 30, 13, 13 );
2. A grid of TubeGeometries forming cloth like structure. something like the image below: 
   [image: cloth]

I am hoping threejs (or experts working with 3D engine like Unity) can provide some inputs on ways to reduce vertices on these geometries.

Comment: There might be ways to use less verts in some of your cases but I also wonder: what is your actual problem? Modern gfx systems can handle a lot of verts if things are efficient otherwise. For example using BufferGeometry in three.js: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry

Comment: @antont Thanks for your response. We are using BufferedGeometry and that definitely helped in terms of memory. what I am trying to achieve now is to reduce the vertices and faces so that our geometries can render with decent FPS even on low end devices like chrome books. 

Here is a quick simplified version on codepen for 1 thread (built using TubeGeometry) and 1 sphere. This example does NOT use bufferGeometry. I can't share the actual scene but it does have 30+ of these threads and 50+ of these spheres:

http://codepen.io/gravi2/pen/PqXbqg?editors=001

Comment: I know I can tweak the parameters to SphereGeometry and TubeGeometry to reduce the vertices, but that ofcourse results in much lower quality geometry.
I also tried out the SimplifyModifier, but have not been able to get it working:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5806

Comment: The example does make it clear, thanks. I don't know how else those could be lighter to render, apart from reducing vertices like you already know. I checked the code of that SimplifyModifier and it doesn't seem to take any parameters so it's not wonder the param you give doesn't change it. I guess it doesn't do anything because your geom is already is as simple as it can be without loosing detail, there are no duplicate verts for example (I don't know that algo though). bjorke's advice to profile where exactly your bottleneck is on those low end devices is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is you problem fill rate or total memory?

If it is fill rate, you will see faster rendering at smaller sizes. If it's CPU memory, smaller sizes will be about the same.

If fill rate, how much depth complexity do you have (# of primitives that share the same pixel)? If it's high, sorting your primitives using renderOrder so that they render nearest-to-furthest should help reduce frame times.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think my problem is total memory. To reduce size, I am using half or 3/4 canvas for rendering and then resizing it using CSS3 scaling. Wondering what else I can do to simplify the geometry. Is the SimplifyModifier suppose to work on the geometries I showed in example?